# How to efficiently superimpose scatter plots in an matplotlib FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to produce a movie showing scatter plots being superimposed of two products derived from a sequence of images (if relevant, there are about 1000 images where each of them have 471x949 pixels).

For each interaction of `FuncAnimation` the arrays are filtered to select the largest values that typically would be seen in this sort of figure and them a scatter plot between them is produced. Around 40k-50k of these pixels usually satisfy this condition.

The idea is to go overploting these scatter plots for each interaction showing how these points will distribute themselves over time.

While the code works the time between each interaction is escalating and to compile a single movie it would take hours and I don't see how to optimize this code to make it produce a movie in a reasonable time.

The code follows below:

```
def anim_scatter(harpnum):
    '''
    Description
    '''
    plt.style.use('dark_background')
    # Defining the top folder containing all the subfolders with the observations.
    path = f'mypath/{harpnum}/'

    # Defining the levels.
    levels=[-1e17,-5e16,-1e16,-5e15,0,5e15,1e16,5e16,1e17]

    # Taking the images paths and trimming the images that are too close to the limb.
    sn_files = sorted(glob(f'{path}Sn/*.npy'))[213:-213]
    bp_files = sorted(glob(f'{path}By/*.npy'))[213:-213]
    bt_files = sorted(glob(f'{path}Bx/*.npy'))[213:-213]
    vn_files = sorted(glob(f'{path}W0/*.npy'))[213:-213]

    # Saving the number of frames.
    n_frames = len(sn_files)

    # Loading the first data.
    s = np.load(sn_files[0])

    # Loading the images and filtering the values of interest based on Sn.
    # Note that the array is also flatenned in the proccess so we can produce 
    # a scatter plot between bt2 and vn.
    bt2 = np.multiply(np.sqrt(np.add(np.power(np.load(bp_files[0]),2),np.power(np.load(bt_files[0]),2))), np.add((s > 5e15).astype(int),(s < -5e15).astype(int))).flatten()
    bt2 = np.delete(bt2,np.argwhere(bt2 == 0))
    vn = np.multiply(np.load(vn_files[0]), np.add((s > 5e15).astype(int),(s < -5e15).astype(int))).flatten()
    vn = np.delete(vn,np.argwhere(vn == 0))

    # Creating the figure objects.
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(14,8))

    # Setting the images
    ax.set_xlim(0,2000)
    ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
    ax.scatter([],[])

    plt.tight_layout()

    def refresher(frame_number):
        '''
        description
        '''
        print(f'Current frame: {frame_number}/{n_frames}')

        # Loading the new data.
        new_sn = np.load(sn_files[frame_number])

        new_bt2 = np.multiply(np.sqrt(np.add(np.power(np.load(bp_files[frame_number]),2),np.power(np.load(bt_files[frame_number]),2))), np.add((new_sn > 5e15).astype(int),(new_sn < -5e15).astype(int))).flatten()
        new_bt2 = np.delete(new_bt2,np.argwhere(new_bt2 == 0))

        new_vn = np.multiply(np.load(vn_files[frame_number]), np.add((new_sn > 5e15).astype(int),(new_sn < -5e15).astype(int))).flatten()
        new_vn = np.delete(new_vn,np.argwhere(new_vn == 0))

        # Creating the new colourmap.
        new_sn_map = np.multiply(new_sn, np.add((new_sn > 5e15).astype(int),(new_sn < -5e15).astype(int))).flatten()
        new_sn_map = np.delete(new_sn_map,np.argwhere(new_sn_map == 0))

        print(len(new_sn_map))

        # Setting the new data.
        ax.scatter(new_bt2,new_vn,s=2,c=new_sn_map,cmap='PRGn',vmin=levels[0],vmax=levels[-1])

        return(fig,)

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, refresher, frames=range(n_frames), blit=True,)
    ani.save(f"mypath/{harpnum}_scatter_test.mp4",fps=10)
    plt.close()
    return
```

What am I missing that is making the time to process each loop escalate? Can it actually be optimized or it is simply accumulating too much information?

EDIT: I've been running some tests and while the time to run the `refresher` function stays stable around 0.33sec the time it takes for each new frame to be add is increasing by around 1sec per interaction.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if that would make your code faster, since I cannot run your code, but your `refresher()` function should return a list of *Artists*, not the reference to the figure. You should store the object returned by `scatter()` and return that.

Comment: you mean set the ```im = ax.scatter([],[])``` , place the ```im``` as an ```farg``` on ```FuncAnimation```, reassign im inside ```refresher()``` and them return ```im```? that was also lagging a bit. I will read the documentation regarding artists now. Thanks for pointing me to that.